# How to mark an URL in a quick way in Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

I often use Notepad++ for manipulating HTML code. Using URLs I would to understand how to quickly select them in order to copy/paste, etc...

Currently I have to select the beginning and the end of the URL, and sometimes I have several problems with my tendons.

Comment: You can always use `SHIFT` and arrows for text selection

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question, you want to be able to highlight a URL in text with a keyboard shortcut? And assuming that's what you want to do, I have no idea, you might want to write your own N++ plugin

Comment: start at the beginning or the URL and use SHIFT+CTRL and then right arrow to select a string up until the next white space, ie. at the end of the URL

Answer (score 0):

Use find with regular expression to isolate the urls.

The regular expression is `"http[s]?:[^"]+"`

As in this screen shot bellow. In the find window select all `findings all in current document`

And see all your findings in the lower window.

[image]

Double click on your chosen url. 
It is now selected.

If you want to select the URL without the wrapping quotes.

The regular expression is: `(?<=["])http[s]?:[^"]+`